# PHP - Add multiple objects into array

Tags: php, arrays

**SAMPLE DATA**

I have the following array of objects example:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(RData)#2 (6) {
    ["DateOfBirth"]=>
    string(10) "1985-01-01"
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(4) "john"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(RData)#3 (6) {
    ["DateOfBirth"]=>
    string(10) "1980-12-12"
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(4) "jane"
  }
}
```

This array is built by essentially concatenating two objects, like follows:

```
$rArray = array(
                    $rData,
                    $rData2
                );
```

**QUESTION**

How can I build this sequentially? Piece by piece (because there are many variations of the end array)...

**I tried:**

```
$rArray = array( $rData );
array_push( $rArray, $rData2 );
```

Didn't work, push overrode current object, expected

**Also tried:**

```
$rArray = array_merge( $rData, $rData2 )
```

Didn't work, expected, they're objects not arrays

Comment: "Concatenating two objects" makes no sense. You're putting two values into an array, no more, no less. Your first and second code sample to do that should be identical. It's unclear why one supposedly isn't working. – *"push overrode current object, expected"* - No, very much unexpected.

Comment: [norepo](https://3v4l.org/NibJT), can you give a small yet _complete_ example of what is not working?

Comment: I don't understand your question? you have already your two objects piece by piece...(`$rdata` and `$rdata2` ) what would you do with us? an array?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney all works as expected - https://eval.in/498706

Comment: Are you trying to convert objects to arrays?

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that:

```
$rArray = array(
            $rData,
            $rData2
          );
```

It is not an object's concatenation, it's just an array's creation with two differents object like that:

```
$rArray = array();    // create array
$rArray[] = $rData;   // add first object
$rArray[] = $rData2;  // add second object
```

Your code create one [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php), contain two [PHP objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) ($rData and $rData2);
You can access to your object with the id of the array like that :

```
$rArray[0] // call the $rdata object
$rArray[1] // call the $rdata2 object
```

And for acces to the object properties :

```
 echo $rArray[0]->DateOfBirth // output : 1985-01-01
```

Or you can iterate on all the array for create an html Table (it's a sample)

```
<?php 
    $table = '<table><tbody>';

    foreach($rArray as $person){
        $table .=  '<tr><td>'.$person->FirstName.'</td><td>'.$person->DateOfBirth .'</td></tr>';
    }

    $table .= '</tbody></table>';

    echo $table; // display the HTML table.
?>
```

Output of the foreach is :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>john</td>
         <td>1985-01-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jane</td>
        <td>1980-12-12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Do you have an other problem with PHP Array and object?